# Related products in product detail page design: Is it a good practice?

Tags: e-commerce

We have an e-commerce website. Often times when a customer selects a product that item has many related products. We're thinking about displaying the all the related items on one product detail page as we don't want users to leave the product page view.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: Why not? Are you worried your user gets lost? Related products on the details page serve several purposes: they can reaffirm you that you're making the right choice or they can steer you towards a better choice. They can even occasionally trigger an add-on sale.

Comment: You should be more clear as the heading of your question and the main body are totally disconnected. Unless read continuously.

Comment: Pointed out as this is a really GOOD question but asked without any details.

Comment: Welcome to UX.stackexchange. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How can you be so sure that the user will HIT the Buy NOW button, if you remove the 'related products' section from detail page? Or, the user will really enjoy the experience of only product details and no other distraction?

The purpose of putting related products is to

- Offer Options to users
- Increase chances of additional sales
- Satisfy the researchers need
- Help users FIND the right product

People visit eCommerce site to buy something and some end up buying more than planned things. Thanks to sections like these

- "Related Products"
- "Customers who viewed this product also viewed.."

> There are 5 main types of e-commerce shoppers. Knowing the different motivations and habits people have when they come to a site helps designers make decisions that improve overall site usability while supporting different users’ needs.

[Researches](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ecommerce-shoppers/) about types of users(shoppers), their behavior indicates that its **more than better to have related products page on product detail page.**

But you should be careful not to clutter the page with too much of additional information.

> Key content requirements for product pages are: answer users’ questions, be direct, and help with product comparison.

And

> Some sites offer users comparison tools that allow shoppers to see products side by side. Depending on the design and the product information included, these tools range from dismal to powerful. Yet we see that when users shop, the most helpful way to allow comparison between products is to provide comparable information, presented in a comparable way, about similar products.  Shoppers struggle when sites offer robust details about one item, and sparse information about another. They are left guessing as to which product better meets their needs.

As said by Jacob Nielsen in one of [ecommerce research](http://www.nngroup.com/articles/product-descriptions/).

Answer (score 0):

By presenting products which are related to the displayed one, you can suggest items that customers can be interested in. It is worth inspiring your clients to buy additional items with **personalized recommendations** because delivering relevant offer provides the opportunity for deeper user's engagement. If you increase the client’s engagement, you also increase the chances for cross-selling and up-selling. **The tools for personalized automatic recommendations and remarketing** can be very useful in this matter. They allow to display products on homepage, category pages, product pages and checkout page.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is called cross selling and it's a good practice. in a fashion e-commerce website we designed, there was 3 kinds of this

- selling similar products (similar looking products of the same category)
- selling products that compliment the current product (complete the look/set)
  -selling products that i very likely to be bought based on previous user habits.